# Bash скрипты условие if

Tags: bash

Постигаю основы bash
Создал test.sh

```
#!/bin/bash
if [ mount | grep -q "/dev/sdb1 on /home/votanko/backup"]
then
echo "mounted"
else
echo "unmounted"
fi
```

Выходит ошибка

```
./troll.sh: строка 2: [: пропущен `]'
unmounted
```

Comment: Посмотрите внимательно примеры условий на баше с квадратными скобками и найдите, чего же не хватает во второй строке.

Comment: if [ $(mount | grep -q "/dev/sdb1 on /home/votanko/backup") ];  
Сделал так, ошибки пропали, но условие не выполняется. Говорит, что не смонтировано, а раздел смонтирован

Comment: Логично. Что возвращает `mount | grep -q "/dev/sdb1 on /home/votanko/backup"`?

Comment: ничего, я думал раз есть логическое или должно  возвращаться true/false

Comment: Немного не так спросил. `grep -q` в данном случае при совпадении шаблона поиска возвращает (код возврата программы) - ноль - `Exit  immediately  with zero status if any match is found`. Поэтому у вас результат совпадения шаблона какбы `false`.

Comment: о, спасибо, буду знать теперь

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`if` проверяет результат команды, так что вам не нужно дополнительно
использовать `test`:

```sh
#!/usr/bin/env bash

if mount | grep -q '/dev/sdb1 on /home/votanko/backup'
then
    echo "mounted"
else
    echo "unmounted"
fi
```

Answer (score 1):

Можете использовать `test` в short варианте

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash

[ `mount | grep -ic '/dev/sdb1 on /home/votanko/backup'` -ge 1 ] && {
    echo Mounted
} || {
    echo Unmounted
}
```

Оно же, но в human-readable варианте
#!/usr/bin/env bash

```
if [ `mount | grep -ic '/dev/sdb1 on /home/votanko/backup'` -ge 1 ]; then
    echo Mounted
else
    echo Unmounted
fi
```